# Ability/setting to not copy blank lines in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, copy-paste

In visual studio there is a setting that enables the editor to know that if I accidentally hit cntrl c but I am on a blank line, it will not copy empty space.

This feature is quite useful and after some googling, I don't believe this feature exists in Android Studio.

However, I wanted to ask others to make sure that this feature doesn't exist because it is very useful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ctrl + alt + shift + /` should show you the following pop up

[image]

clicking on Registry you should get

[image]

look for `editor.skip.copy.and.cut.for.empty.selection` and check it. Tested on AS 1.4 for `Linux`.

**Edit**

On Mac the shortcut is `cmd + shift + alt + /`

Comment: Thanks. I hated this in Visual Studio and hate it in Android Studio. I think this should be disabled by default. How the heck would want to copy an empty string to the clipboard?

Comment: Now I am satisfied with android studio. I hated this feature. You are genius Blackbelt

Comment: Nice 1 @Blackbelt, upvoted for working solution and for those who are not able to open registry with this shortcut key, then go to your `keymap` and add  a shortcut key for `registry` (please google if you don't know how to configure keymap)and use that shortcut key for open registry dialog.